# Prestashop admin panel is lost after trying to export language packet

Tags: prestashop

There were some language problems in my site which uses a specific theme so I thought,I should pick out the language pack edit and reload it. Because I couldn't find a way to edit it using browser on admin panel.

I just pressed a button named **export language packet**. I don't know if something happened that time. But it didn't give me a file (an exported file I mean) . So I didn't do anything else. But since that time I can't reach my admin panel. While I write the URL it shows me a big white screen.

On the other side the site itself (not admin panel) is reachable. What can I do to fix my problem?

Hi,
This is the error

```
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting ']' in C:\wamp\www\httpdocs\translations\tr\admin.php on line 586
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0009  690552  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   1.7995  9942280 DispatcherCore->dispatch( ) ..\index.php:50
3   2.0567  10375504    ControllerCore::getController( )    ..\Dispatcher.php:342
4   2.0686  12512728    AdminControllerCore->__construct( ) ..\Controller.php:128
5   2.0689  12514200    AdminControllerCore->l( )   ..\AdminController.php:304
6   2.0711  12612344    TranslateCore::getAdminTranslation( )   ..\AdminController.php:1737
```

Comment: Please enable errors in PS. Open config/defines.inc.php and change define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false); to define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true); . After that, refresh the page. If you see any errors update your question with that error(s) . After i will try to provide you any solution .

Comment: Hi, I enabled the errors and added the resulting error on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you got is in your translation file in file translations\tr\admin.php  on line number 586.

To fix that error,  take a backup of that file, i.e. keep a copy of that file in some other place, then try to find out the syntax error you got there. It is some kind of PHP syntax error there in that translation file. As the translation file is only for the admin section, therefore your site front end may be fine and your site admin section is not working.

If you are not able to find that error and fix it, then delete all contents from that file, and then try to load the admin section.

You should use a translation pack which is provided by prestashop, ie download it from the prestashop  http://www.prestashop.com/en/translations .

Also if you want to edit translations, use admin. In your question you mentioned, that you were not able to edit translations, please do provide details for that problem, and also try to edit translations while keeping error reporting on, so if there is any problem, you will get the errors printed. If you got errors printed, then update your question with that error message.

Let me know if you still got any questions.

Comment: Hi,I don't know how this  translations\tr\admin.php file is corrupted because I didn't edit it. I have copies of initial version of my store so changed the file. Now I can reach my store :) Thank you